# Getting .wl file without appending global' before variable names

Tags: import, variable-definitions

I have a .wl file created using mathematica that contains:

```
list = {{a->4, b->5}}
```

When I read it in using Get["file.wl"] it reads in as:

```
{{Global'a->4, Global'b->5}}
```

How do I read it in without appending the global tags?

Comment: For me, no context marks are included. Is that the exact content of the file in your question? What version of Mathematica are you using? Finally, what is the value of `$Context` and `$ContextPath`? And what do you get if you change the file to `list = {{a->4, b->5},$Context,$ContextPath}`?

Comment: MMA version 13.1. I get  {{a->4, b->5}}

Comment: I'm using version 13.0.1, I was able to fix it by switching the notebooks context to global